# Extension of functions with bounded derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Consider an analytic function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed set and let $L$ be a positive constant such that $\|\nabla f(x)\|\le L$ for all $x\in A$, where $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$ and $\|{\cdot}\|$ is a norm. I wonder whether there exists a function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

$(1)$ $F\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$;

$(2)$ $F(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in A$;

$(3)$ $\|\nabla F(x)\|\le L$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

In other words, $F$ extends condition $(3)$ from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with or without analyticity.

Comment: There seems to be a theorem which, applied on $\nabla f$ or the corresponding differential, would give your result, the [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem), but I'm not sure of the details myself. For example I don't know if it can be proved that the extension of $\nabla f$ is itself the gradient of a function $F$.

Answer (score 2):

In general this extension is not possible.  Let $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be any analytic function with two critical points $p\neq q$ with $f(p)\neq f(q)$.  Then take $A=\{p,q\}$, and note that the assumptions are satisfied for any $L>0$.  But if there is an extension as described, we have the bound $$|f(p)-f(q)|\leq \int_p^q\left|\frac{dF}{dx}\right|\,dx\leq L|p-q|$$ for all $L>0$, whereby $f(p)=f(q)$, a contradiction.

One gets similar contradictions in higher dimensions, letting $A$ be the set of critical points of $f$.

Comment: Nice example! Thank you very much for the help!